# How convert epoch time to string?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a data array 10000*3 that need to save as a csv file.Below is my pseudo code, but I don't know how to achive it only with numpy(not pandas).Can someone know how to do?

```py
import numpy as np
import time 
arr = np.random.randn(10000, 3)

# That need  arr[0,0] = time.time(), arr[i, 0] = time.time()  + i
arr[:,0] = time.time() + 1

# And after that, I need to  column 1 to datatime string(like "2021-02-12 12:12:12")
arr[:,0] need to apply `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(item))` this function.

# After that, the data type is, column1:str, column2:float, column3:float and to save it as a csv file.
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `import csv` (pre-installed with python default packages). See this tutorial for examples: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

```
with open('countries.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write the data
    for row in arr:
         writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The efficiency is too low, my code source data file is  numpy style and 100 files 40M size.